# Unable to change vm.max_map_count for elasticsearch

Tags: java, centos6, elasticsearch, sugarcrm

### Prehistory

I have elasticsearch and SugarCRM7 running on CentOS 6.5. Every day I face the same problem: java outOfMemory error. That happens because of small vm.max_map_count value, 65530 only when 262144 is recommended.

### Problem

The problem is that vm.max_map_count seems unchangeable:

1. Changing under root

   ```
   sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
   ```

   returns

   > error: permission denied on key 'vm.max_map_count'

   While

   ```
   ps aux | grep java
   ```

   Returns only the grep process
2. Changing on elasticsearch startup

   ```
   sudo service elasticsearch start
   ```

   Returns error, too

   > error: permission denied on key 'vm.max_map_count'
   >
   > Starting elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
3. Manual changes via file (dirty-dirty hack):

   ```
   sudo vi /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
   ```

   Does not work either:

   > "/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" [readonly] 1L, 6C
   >
   > -- INSERT -- W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
   >
   > E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
   >
   > "/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" E212: Can't open file for writing

   While

   ```
   ls -la /proc/sys/vm/ | grep max_map_count
   ```

   Returns

   > -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 10 09:36 max_map_count

   (But I guess this can be normal for linux talking about /proc directory)

So how can I change this variable's value? Restarting elasticsearch every night is not a good idea... Or at least may be someone knows why this error happens?

Comment: What kind of a machine it is? Virtual? If so what kind of virtualization is used? Note that some virtualizations e.g., OpenVZ containers impose limitation on your container, and doesn't allow you to "tweak" kernel and other low level stuff.

Comment: @MiroslavKoskar I do not know, unfortunately. How can I find it out?

Comment: @MiroslavKoskar Forgot to mention — the machine is virtual, of course

Comment: How to find out? Well, where it is hosted? It should be rather obvious because it's usually part of your contract with your hosting provider. If still in doubt, contact your hosting provider support, IMHO that's the best place to start (since it's usually part of the deal and something you are likely paying for).

Comment: @MiroslavKoskar well, the provider answered without mentioning the technology that they can not help me with this problem (that is rather reasonably). Thanks for your help

Comment: You find out by running `virt-what` (and installing it, if it is not already present).

Answer (score 16):

you are almost there, It does not matter if is a virtual machine or a physical machine, those settings are always changeable.

I'll show 3 methods.

Some pre-information:

1) It's better to execute as root, if possible.

2) **/proc** on unix is not a real filesystem, it's a in-memory kernel file system, but it appears to be like a normal disk file system. You can call it 'fake filesystem' or 'special filesystem', you cannot edit those fake-files with vi or any other editor, because they are not files, they just look like files. I stuck with the same problem years ago.

But it's simple to change their values, just require another kind of 'mechanics' to edit them.

I'll will explain:
First, need to be root: (sudo does work in some distros, but does not on some other distros like you tried, this first method is universal and works on any Linux, macOS, or any Unix-based. Hope you have access to root password.

Proceed at prompt:

```
    $ su root
```

Enter root password.

Now you are root, let's check the current value of: **/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count**

```
    $ cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count  
    65536
```

Let's change it:

```
    echo 262144 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

Let's verify:

```
    cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
    262144
```

It's done! 
And it's already applied and functional. By changing values of any pseudo-file under /proc the settings becomes active instantly. But they don't persist after a reboot. You can play with values and measure performance changes at **elasticsearh** or any other application or system metrics. Go tunning your system, writing the values on some paper, keep the best values. On any mistake, reboot and they will all be back to original values, and start again until all wished values are optimal. There's a lot of disk and memory tunnable parameters under /proc. And they make a huge difference and performance gain if you to tune them well (and have time for it). You are on the right way.

When satisfied, let's make them permanent:

**First method:**

using **/etc/rc.local**

```
    vi /etc/rc.local
```

put all parameters inside rc.local file, example:

```
    echo 220000000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
    echo 320000000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
    echo 500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
    echo 4500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rfc1337
    echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
    echo 120 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode
    echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
    echo 8 > /sys/class/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb
    echo 1048575 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

quit vi editor saving the file.

Those parameters will be set on every reboot, AFTER all init services have started, just before the login prompt shows.

*(**/etc/rc.local** file is executed after all startup linux services, it may not work if elasticsearch starts before it as a service, but this method can be useful on another setup if you need in future, or you can use like this by putting them inside your elasticsearch init script, because init script run as root, so it's the same syntax above to use inside init scripts)*

You can also copy them now and paste them for instant changes. The parameters above are valid, tuned and running on my apache cassandra server. 
If you wish, try them as a start point to tune yours.

**Second method to make them permanent:**

Parameters now will be set BEFORE any startup service on linux.

Edit **/etc/sysctl.conf**, put parameters inside

```
 vm.max_map_count=1048575
 vm.zone_reclaim_mode=0
 vm.dirty_background_bytes=220000000
 vm.dirty_background_ratio=0
 vm.dirty_bytes=320000000
 vm.dirty_ratio=0
 vm.swappiness=10
```

keep going with the others, save **/etc/sysctl.conf**, reboot your server to apply changes, or execute: **sysctl -p** to apply the changes without reboot. They will be permanent across reboots.

Two methods above are the most commom. There's another one, and it may work for you, it's by using **sudo**, almost like you were doing:

instead of:

```
  sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

try:

```
  echo 262144 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

It works on ubuntu.

Verify:

```
   user@naos:~$ cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
   262144
```

Hope I have helped someway, at least by giving the 3 different options to deal with the problem, since it's almost a year old your question ;)

Regards,
Rafael Prado

Comment: They already _did_ this, and it failed.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes you are right. I understood at first that the problem was related to the operating system CentOS and unix user permissions, so I followed that line on my answer. But newer information put the focus of the problem on the "host" OpenVZ, which limits some settings. 
My knowledge is on Centos and VmWare, but not on OpenVZ.

Answer (score 5):

I think your "virtual machine" is actually an OpenVZ container (which you can verify this by running `virt-what`).

In this case, you can't change `vm.max_map_count` sysctl or many others. The values are fixed.

This is a well known issue with elasticsearch ([issue #4978](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4978)). It's not just Elasticsearch. Java apps are well known to perform poorly on various OpenVZ providers, mainly because the hosts are often poorly tuned and there's nothing you can do about it. One commenter on that issue echoed what would be my recommendation exactly:

> joshuajonah commented on Oct 20, 2015
>   This is insane. I guess I'm going to change over to a KVM VPS.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow official instructions:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

To make change permanent update the vm.max_map_count setting in /etc/sysctl.conf

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html